# Is there some DevTool to view MsgPack requests / responses?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, msgpack

I've been searching and I can't seem to find anything. Not sure if anyone knows of an easy way to see `MsgPack` requests and responses in the `network` tab?